# Switch places on all neighboring even and odd numbers in a list. (the list should be: [1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8,..., 98])

Tags: python, list

Please help. i think i am really close to getting the right answer, but not there yet. This is how far i have made it:

```
data=np.arange(1,101,dtype=int) 
for i in range(len(data)): 
if(i%2==1): 
    data[i]= #i am missing something here

print(data)
```

here is a pictue and as you can see i have managed to make ever even number too zero, but i want the even numbers to be change positon with the odd number. so 1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTHc9.png)

Comment: `arange` should start from `0`. This can be simply done by `data + 1 - 2*(data%2)`.

Comment: Your arange starts at 1 not 0.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is the solution

```
data=np.arange(0,100,dtype=int) 
i=0
while i<len(data)-1:
    temp = data[i]
    data[i] = data[i+1]
    data[i+1] = temp
    i+=2

print(data)
```

Ouput I got

[ 1  0  3  2  5  4  7  6  9  8 11 10 13 12 15 14 17 16 19 18 21 20 23 22
25 24 27 26 29 28 31 30 33 32 35 34 37 36 39 38 41 40 43 42 45 44 47 46
49 48 51 50 53 52 55 54 57 56 59 58 61 60 63 62 65 64 67 66 69 68 71 70
73 72 75 74 77 76 79 78 81 80 83 82 85 84 87 86 89 88 91 90 93 92 95 94
97 96 99 98]

Comment: not very pythonic, but classic bubble sort logic

Comment: You really don't need an additional temporary variable to swap two values. `data[i], data[i+1] = data[i+1], data[i]` will work fine.

Comment: yeh.. thats why I did comment it is just classic bubble sort from c++.. You are right though